# Ubuntu + Wacom Intuos 4 + MyPaint HELP!

Tags: usb, wacom, graphics-tablet

Please keep in mind I'm not that computer savvy, but I will try any suggestion so please help me out!

My tablet will stop working if the USB connection is ever broken, or the Ubuntu software is being updated. Sometimes it will stop working for no reason that I can see. The lights will still be on, but it won't be responsive. It doesn't work again until I restart the laptop with the tablet plugged in, which is grating if you have to do it every 25 min. or so... I'm not sure if the issue is with the port, the tablet/cable or the driver but any suggestions would be very welcome!

Also, MyPaint is frequently having hiccups. It seems to save fine but at times it will randomly close down and when I open files they're often empty. They turn into 0Kb files and only contain a single empty layer. Also very grating, considering I lose days of work for no clear reason and without any heads up. Again, I'm not sure if the issue is with the port, the tablet/cable or the driver but any suggestions would be very welcome!

The error message reads;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/mypaint/gui/application.py", line 177, at_application_start(*junk=())
                    else:
                        self.filehandler.open_file(fn)
  variables: {'fn': ('local', u'/home/maria/Desktop/Drawings/WIPs/Sativa Chibi.ora'), 'self.filehandler.open_file': ('local', <bound method FileHandler.wrapper of <gui.filehandling.FileHandler object at 0x7fdb89063a10>>)}
  File "/usr/share/mypaint/gui/drawwindow.py", line 60, wrapper(self=<gui.filehandling.FileHandler object>, *args=(u'/home/maria/Desktop/Drawings/WIPs/Sativa Chibi.ora',), **kwargs={})
            try:
                func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                # gtk main loop may be called in here...
  variables: {'self': ('local', <gui.filehandling.FileHandler object at 0x7fdb89063a10>), 'args': ('local', (u'/home/maria/Desktop/Drawings/WIPs/Sativa Chibi.ora',)), 'func': ('local', <function open_file at 0x7fdb8b397b90>), 'kwargs': ('local', {})}
  File "/usr/share/mypaint/gui/filehandling.py", line 231, open_file(self=<gui.filehandling.FileHandler object>, filename=u'/home/maria/Desktop/Drawings/WIPs/Sativa Chibi.ora')
            try:
                self.doc.model.load(filename, feedback_cb=self.gtk_main_tick)
            except document.SaveLoadError, e:
  variables: {'self.doc.model.load': ('local', <bound method Document.load of <lib.document.Document instance at 0x7fdb8ab4f8c0>>), 'feedback_cb': (None, []), 'self.gtk_main_tick': ('local', <function gtk_main_tick at 0x7fdb8b397b18>), 'filename': ('local', u'/home/maria/Desktop/Drawings/WIPs/Sativa Chibi.ora')}
  File "/usr/share/mypaint/lib/document.py", line 544, load(self=<lib.document.Document instance>, filename=u'/home/maria/Desktop/Drawings/WIPs/Sativa Chibi.ora', **kwargs={'feedback_cb': <function gtk_main_tick>})
            try:
                load(filename, **kwargs)
            except gobject.GError, e:
  variables: {'load': ('local', <bound method Document.load_ora of <lib.document.Document instance at 0x7fdb8ab4f8c0>>), 'kwargs': ('local', {'feedback_cb': <function gtk_main_tick at 0x7fdb8b397b18>}), 'filename': ('local', u'/home/maria/Desktop/Drawings/WIPs/Sativa Chibi.ora')}
  File "/usr/share/mypaint/lib/document.py", line 772, load_ora(self=<lib.document.Document instance>, filename=u'/home/maria/Desktop/Drawings/WIPs/Sativa Chibi.ora', feedback_cb=<function gtk_main_tick>)
                tempdir = tempdir.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
            z = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)
            print 'mimetype:', z.read('mimetype').strip()
  variables: {'zipfile.ZipFile': ('global', <class 'zipfile.ZipFile'>), 'z': (None, []), 'filename': ('local', u'/home/maria/Desktop/Drawings/WIPs/Sativa Chibi.ora')}
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 770, __init__(self=<zipfile.ZipFile object>, file=u'/home/maria/Desktop/Drawings/WIPs/Sativa Chibi.ora', mode='r', compression=0, allowZip64=False)
                if key == 'r':
                    self._RealGetContents()
                elif key == 'w':
  variables: {'self._RealGetContents': ('local', <bound method ZipFile._RealGetContents of <zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x7fdb9b952790>>)}
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 811, _RealGetContents(self=<zipfile.ZipFile object>)
            if not endrec:
                raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
            if self.debug > 1:
  variables: {'BadZipfile': ('global', <class 'zipfile.BadZipfile'>)}
BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: You should learn how to format posts: http://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

This is a **workaround**.

Instead of rebooting, when the tablet stops working, you can try to:

1. Unplug the tablet
2. In a terminal, issue the command:

   ```
   sudo rmmod wacom
   ```

   (ignore errors here. This command unload the driver; if it has been unloaded before for whatever reason it can spew an error)
3. Reload the driver:

   ```
   sudo modprobe wacom
   ```
4. plug the tablet again.

You can try to switch step 3 and 4 too.

*Notice however* that many programs will not detect the tablet unless stopped and restarted.

The correct solution would be to understand where the problem is. A broken cable can really mess things up; this would be the first thing I'll check. You can try to see if you have some error in `/var/log/syslog` when the problem occurs.